# why the curl could not access website when using proxy

Tags: terminal, curl, proxy

I am using macOS 13 and set the proxy in terminal like this:

```
➜  depot_tools git:(d9e2d479) env|grep all_proxy
all_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:7890
```

then I using the curl command like this:

```
➜  depot_tools git:(d9e2d479) curl -L -v https://www.facebook.com
* Uses proxy env variable all_proxy == 'socks5://127.0.0.1:7890'
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:7890...
* SOCKS5 connect to IPv4 31.13.76.99:443 (locally resolved)
* SOCKS5 request granted.
* Connected to (nil) (127.0.0.1) port 7890 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to www.facebook.com:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to www.facebook.com:443
```

I am sure the `127.0.0.1:7890` works because I can using it in google chrome to access facebook. Am I missing something, is is possible to fixed this problem?